# Secure MS Access database in Windows Application

Tags: vb.net, security, ms-access

I have created a Windows Application in Vb.Net using MS Access 2007 database. I want it to be secured in such a way that the user who uses the application must not be able to see its content or access it. Protecting the file with password isn't a secure way.

Need help to secure and protect the MS Access database.

Answer (score 0):

You said that protecting the file with password is not a secure way. Why? If that's not the secured way for you, you can encrypt all your records using some sort of algorithms. You can also hide the database file on the other directory (*not on the same location as you EXE file*).

Comment: Google can crack the password in minutes.
Well, Encryption is a way I have considered but I would have to perform decryption nearly 4-5 times to 1000 entries of data in a single run of application.
Hiding of data is not full-proof.

Comment: @abhi154 why not use `SQL Server` or `MySQL`?

Comment: @John.. The client is going to prepare the database in access and I am going to just attach it in the application.
Well, I have worked with SQL Server a lot of times and it is a secure thing! Thanks for your suggestions!